# Cannot update record, foreign key null error Entity Framework 5

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

If I add a new foreign key object and save, it works. If I add to the list of foreign key objects and save it works. However if I remove the list and then add new records, it fails with the error "Cannot insert the value NULL into column" and the foreign key is omitted from the update query.

EF:

```
public class TestIdentityDbContext : IdentityDbContext<TestUser>
{
    public TestIdentityDbContext ()
        : base("TestIdentityEntities")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<UserAddress> UserAddresses { get; set; }
}
```

Models:

```
public class TestUser : IdentityUser
{
    public TestUser()
    {
        this.Address = new List<UserAddress>();
    }
    public string SessionId { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<UserAddress> Address { get; set; } 
}

[Table("UserAddress")]
public partial class UserAddress
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string BuildingName { get; set; }
    public string UnitNumber { get; set; }
    public string StreetAddress { get; set; }
    public string PoBox { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
    public string StateRegion { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public TestUser TestUser { get; set; }
}
```

Add New Address:

```
    public void UpdateUser(TradeulatorUser user)
    {
        var loadedUser = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == user.UserName);

        loadedUser.SessionId = user.SessionId ;

        //loadedUser.Address.Clear();                                  

        foreach (var address in user.Address)
        {
            loadedUser.Address.Add(address)
        }
        _context.Users.AddOrUpdate(loadedUser);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Note the line commented out. If this line is commented out, everything works and new addresses are appended to any already existing addresses and saved to the database. Even if there are no addresses currently for the user, the new addresses will be added and it works. However if I uncomment the line to clear the addresses and try to save new addresses, thats when I get the error "Cannot insert the value NULL into column UserId on table UserAddress. Does not allow nulls" or something along those lines.
What am I missing?

Comment: Are you using code-first or db-first approach? Also does the exception get thrown as the `.Clear()` line executes, or when `.SubmitChanges()` is called?

Comment: I'm using db-first and the exception is thrown on savechanges.